# Deploy static website to IIS from VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a Git repository hosted in Visual Studio Team Services that I need to mirror to a remote IIS wwwroot directory.

Seems silly, but I'm used to doing build/deploy on more complex ASP.NET sites, but with this particular project, all I need to do is mirror the Git repository to a remote IIS machine and I'm not sure of what's the best approach.

What's the most reasonably way to "build" a package of the static HTML files/images, etc and send them to the IIS server?

I'd still like to be able to use the whole "build" and "release" paradigm.  Does the build just become a "zip" file that gets "deployed"/uploaded and unzipped in the remote IIS directory?

Is there a template available for this type of deployment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following steps:

1. In Build, use [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts) task to publish build artifacts.
2. In Release, use [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task to copy artifacts to the emote IIS wwwroot directory.

Comment: Ty!  Is there an easy way to limit the release to only files that were changed since the last release?  The repository is 20 gigs... :-/